# Matching anagrams and pushing to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, push, anagram

I have a given `word`, that I want to match against a given list of words, `mainList`, and establish which words of that given list are anagrams of the given word, and add them to another list, `subList`.

I feel like my method to do this is fine, but it returns an unexpected result.

For example...

```
var word = 'master';
var mainList = ['stream', 'pidgeon', 'maters'];
var subList = [];
```

Then I take the word, split to an array of letters, alphabetise, and join back into a string. With this string I should be able match against any possible anagrams (which I will covert in the same way).

```
var mainSorted = [];

  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
     mainSorted = word.split('').sort().join();
  }
```

This is where it goes wrong. I loop through the `mainList` array trying to establish if a given item, when converted, matches the original. If so, I want to `push` the word to the `subList` array.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < mainList.length; i++) {
     var subSorted = mainList[i].split('').sort().join;
     if (mainSorted === subSorted) {
        subList.push(mainList[i])
     }
  }
  return subList;
```

...and the value I expect to see for subList is: `['stream', 'maters']`

Yet I am returned an empty array instead.

I've gone through this so many times and I cannot see what's going wrong, would really appreciate some help!

Also, I'm aware there's probably more eloquent methods to do this (and I welcome any suggestions) but primarily I want to see where this is going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot () at the end of join

```
var subSorted = mainList[i].split('').sort().join;
```

should be

```
var subSorted = mainList[i].split('').sort().join();
```

One non-issue is

for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
     mainSorted = word.split('').sort().join();
  }

doesnt need to be in a loop

```
 mainSorted = word.split('').sort().join();
```

alone suffices

as a bonus, here's a tidier way of doing what you are doing

```
var word = 'master';
var mainList = ['stream', 'pidgeon', 'maters'];

var mainSorted = word.split('').sort().join();

return mainList.filter(function(sub) {
    return sub.split('').sort().join() == mainSorted;
});
```

Comment: I've been bashing my head against a brick wall, and THAT was the issue all along. HA. Thanks!! :)

Comment: Not sure why I made a loop for `mainSorted` that's pretty obvious in retrospect. As for `filter()`, haven't really started using that yet but looks like a better alternative - thanks for this tip.